# error while converting the json column to text in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I am trying to convert the json column to text

```
SELECT json_data->>'text' AS text
    FROM table1
```

it is giving below error

```
SQL Error [22P05]: ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence Detail: \u0000 cannot be converted to text. Where: JSON data, line 2:   "j_description":...
```

I tried replacing the "\u0000" sequences with ''

```
SELECT regexp_replace(json_data, '\u0000', '', 'g')->>'text' AS text
    FROM table1
```

it is giving below error

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function regexp_replace(json, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I also tried with below script, but, no luck

```
 SELECT regexp_replace(json_data::text, '\u0000', '', 'g')->>'text' AS text
    FROM table1

 SELECT regexp_replace(cast(json_data as text, '\u0000', '', 'g')->>'text' AS text
    FROM table1
```

could someone advice me, please.

thank you

Comment: can you also provide a json example that are you trying to convert ? i mean a simple reproductible example

Comment: {
  "j_description": "2.12.0",
  "j_description1": false,
  "j_description2": "employee",
  "j_description2": "HK345FG", 
}

Comment: yes, i added an answer can you check also i put some references to type conversions on posgresql

Comment: Sorry, I confused you.I want to get a elimant in json and convert it into text, For example:   SELECT json_data->>'j_description1' AS description1 FROM table1

Comment: ok, i am going to update my answer, no problem )

Comment: i made an update, can you check ? and give me feedback if it was helpful.

Comment: unfortunately, same error :                                                                                            
 SQL Error [22P05]: ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence
  Detail: \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
  Where: JSON data, line 2:   "j_description":...

Comment: i did it one more time, can you check now ?

Comment: thank you a lot for your help.  Unfortunately , it is the same error again :(

Comment: more details, please )))

Comment: the error is:                                                                                                           DBSQLException: SQL Error [22P05]: ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence
  Detail: \u0000 cannot be converted to text.                                                       Where: JSON data, line 2:   "c_description"

Comment: I mean the details about new error message and simple reproducible example as update of the question, by the way I think is a good topic for another question.

Comment: I m going to check this one

Comment: the error is: DBSQLException: SQL Error [22P05]: ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence Detail: \u0000 cannot be converted to text. Where: JSON data, line 2: "c_description"

Comment: I used this query :                                                                                                 
 SELECT regexp_replace(json_data::text, '\u0000', '')::json->>'j_description'::text 
as id from table1
where regexp_replace(json_data::text, '\u0000', '')::json->>'j_description'::text is not null
limit 100;

Comment: i have just made last update to this topic,I think it is going to help you. And a good way is to do next steps in your own and also my answer should solve the problem because I did it on my own and it is a tested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something wrong:

Just do:

```
SELECT json_data::text FROM table1
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT json_data->>'text' AS text
FROM table1
```

**UPDATE:**

The Select should look so:

```
SELECT json_data->>'j_description'::text as result from table1;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT regexp_replace(json_data::text, '\u0000', 'newOne')::json->>'j_description'::text as result from table1;
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on this kind of problem a good solution in my opinion contains 2 steps:

1. Do clean of all columns and replace `\u0000` to   something like.

   ```
    update table1
    set json_data = REPLACE(json_data::text, '\u0000', '' )::json 
    where json_data::text like '%\u0000%';
   ```

2.The select will work well without any `regex_replace`

```
SELECT json_data->>'j_description'::text as result from table1;
```

Finally you should do it for all columns that you need `json_data` here is for an example.